# How to wait for a binding to get its value before performing a task

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I've got a directive which performs a task on a model, but I'm having problems waiting for the value to be true before running the outcommented loop, which should decide if the directive should have a state of `true` or `false` value when first initiating the directive.

The only solution to this which I could come up with is by using `ngDoCheck` but I've not been able to find a way to kill this once the `this.model` has had its value completely resolved.

I don't want it to run after I've done the initiating. I also tried using `ngOnInit` and `AfterViewInit` but these obviously doesn't help in this matter.

So how can I wait for `this.model` to get its value before performing a task?

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[checkAll]',
  inputs: [
    'model'
  ]
})

export class CheckAllDirective {

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {

    // TODO: Need to wait for this.model to set before performing this
    // for (let checkbox of this.model) {
    //
    //   if (checkbox.isChecked) {
    //     this.isAllChecked = true;
    //   }
    //   else {
    //     this.isAllChecked = false;
    //   }
    // }

    this.eventHandler = _renderer.listen(_elementRef.nativeElement, ('ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchend' : 'click'), (e) => {

      this.isAllChecked = !this.isAllChecked;

      for (let checkbox of this.model) {
        checkbox.isChecked = this.isAllChecked;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html) is called every time after inputs are updated.

[ngOnInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html) is called after `ngOnChanges` was called the first time.

```
export class CheckAllDirective {

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
     for (let checkbox of this.model) {

       if (checkbox.isChecked) {
         this.isAllChecked = true;
       }
       else {
         this.isAllChecked = false;
       }
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Any information why that wouldn't work? If you want to do something when inputs are set, these two are the way to go. Perhaps the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: I got a core component which just holds some dummy data atm, it's an array of objects. I pass this array into the directive, but it says that it cannot read `.length` of undefined when I try running the loop :/

Comment: I can make a fiddle if you can hang on for a sec.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a problem with the way you use it. Can you reproduce in a Plunker or provide more code that shows where the data comes from and how you pass it to this component. If `ngOnInit()` doesn't work, try `ngOnChanges()` and check if the data is set. `ngOnChanges` can be called more than once. Maybe the data becomes only available after `ngOnInit()` because the component that passes it along receives it **after** `ngOnInit()` of this component is called.

Comment: If you post the link in a comment below I get notified.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/arROwxsFYraSBeAZCIYF?p=preview when the model is pre-defined in the app component it works, but since the checkbox component runs the task of creating the model from the array of objects (the objects which have `isChecked` set to `true`), it seems like the problem is like you said. It runs the init function too soon.

Comment: I'm not on the computer and haven't checked your Plunker yet. Just use `ngOnChanges()` and add an if so it doesn't fail if the data is not yet available

Comment: I did try it and it works, I'm just curious if there's a way to stop listening for changes once I've done what I have to. Don't want unnecessary change detection.

Comment: Change detection runs anyway, no matter if there is an `ngOnChanges()` or not. `ngOnChanges()` is only called when one of the inputs changed. I guess that wont be often anyway. And no, there is no way to disable. You could switch CD to `OnPush` but when inputs change it would run anyway.

Comment: Ok, so NgOnChanges is just a helper to gain access to the changed information?